# PlayFramework2 Date binding

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

Using PlayFramework 2.3 (Java), I'm trying to something equivalent to:
(in my routes file)

```
GET /api/somemethod @controller.someCtrl.someMethod(date: Date)
```

Unfortunately this does not work as Date is not a supported format. What would be the best way to pass in a date from the frontend to the play server? I believe Spring handles this by parsing the request body and extracting the date from it, then passing that to your controller. I'm hoping Play has something equivalent!

Comment: Have you tried to use a String parameter and parse in the controller method?

Comment: Well that is an option I was considering, unfortunately the downside is that the signature of the controller does not explicitly show that it needs a date to function. It might be a minor issue, but I was hoping there was a workaround for that.

Comment: Passing a `long` (unix milliseconds) would probably be better than `String`.

Comment: But it will suffer from the Year 2038 problem :P

Comment: As will anything else.